# How to format JSON in Javascript using the DOM2 method?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, json

I am trying to build a live commenting system for my website (blog page homework). The idea is to use ajax to store comments in a mysql database and return JSON text for a comment without refreshing. I am 90% done with this I am just not sure how to format the JSON text to not look like crap.

The JSON returned for a comment is the following:

> [{"c_name":"Test Commenter","c_date":"2014-08-14","comment":"This is a
>   test comment"}]

On my comment page (postdetails.php) firstly I query the comments database table and return all the comments already stored for a particular post. The user then can enter a comment form > submit it > and the JSON text returned from the ajax function will appear on the page automatically.

The initial comments already stored in the table are displayed via a php function:

> ```
> // Display comments in nice format 
>           while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
>           {
>               echo "<div class = 'comments_user'>\n"; 
>                   echo "<p>" . $row2['c_name'] ."</p>\n";
>               echo "</div>\n"; 
>               echo "<p class = 'date'>" . $row2['c_date'] . "</p>"; 
>               echo "<p>" . $row2['comment'] ."</p>\n"; 
>           }
> ```

My issue is getting the JSON text to display in a similar format underneath the previous comments. I have plain old HTML to display the JSON returned comments. Which I should be able to manipulate with the DOM by targeting the p tag id's shown below :

```
    <!--Use JS and the DOM to manipulate this (live commenting)-->
        <div class = "comments_user">
            <p id = "commenter"></p>
        </div>
        <div class = "date_wrap">
            <p id = "c_date"></p>
        </div>
            <p id = "comment_content"></p>
        <hr/>
        </div>
```

The JSON text is returned in the 'result' variable. This is passed to my JSON_to_HTML function:

```
function JSON_to_HTML(result){
    var CM = JSON.parse(result);        

   // Need to traverse the DOM and display the array contents (JSON)
}
```

My question is how can I add these comments using the DOM to the plain HTML code shown above? I know i can get the p-tag values using document.getElementById("c_date"); and so forth but how can I append children onto these? I am familiar with the Jquery append method but for this I can ONLY use vanilla Javascript.

One thing I tried was to have a global variable to track how many times the ajax function was called (number of comments per session). For each comment I could traverse the DOM and append a child to the commenter, date and comment page. However I was not able to get this quite working.

My last resort would be to return the JSON into a simple table (which I know how to do).

Any ideas here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have the html structure in place, you can do:

```
document.getElementById("c_date").textContent = CM[0].c_date;
// etc.
```

And if you want to add html instead of plain text, you can use `innerHTML` instead.

Comment: This is a great start but leads to another problem. This will work to display one single comment but as soon as a user enters a second comment the p tag will be overwritten. Any ideas how I can allow multiple comments? I feel like I could use something similar to Jquerys append() but I'm not sure of a vanilla JS equivalent.

Comment: @user3055632 That's really another question but using `innerHTML` instead of `textContent` you can easily add / modify elements. Just make sure that the ID's remain unique.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I suppose multiple HTML divs could be assigned on the page and filled in for each comment. Maybe only allowing a user to enter 5 comments max at one time. Ill try this out.

Comment: @user3055632 There are no limits, just build an html block in your function (or get it from a template) and add it at the correct location. You can also use `appendChild` for that.